# NGINX and PHP-FPM is downloading index.php instead of processing it

Tags: nginx, php

I recently installed NGINX and PHP-FPM on a Centos6 server. I'm able to view other php pages on my site, but for some reason my index.php file gets downloaded rather than processed like a normal php page.

Here is the nginx config:

```
# The default server
#
server {
listen       80 default_server;
server_name  example.com;

#charset koi8-r;

#access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /var/www/html/;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}

error_page  404              /404.html;
location = /index.php {
    root   /var/www/html;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /var/www/html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to remove this block:

```
location = /index.php {
    root   /var/www/html;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation as to why this happens would've got you `+1` from me

Comment: I believe because it comes before the "location ~ \.php$" block and matches /index.php it executes first, and doesn't include any of the fastcgi commands to actually tell nginx to make the call to fastcgi... so nginx serves up the php file as a binary download because it doesn't know what to do with a .php file